# Simple Angular Form Validation Not Working

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have a simple Angular form here:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="alertForm">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cautionMultiplier" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Yellow Multiplier</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" ng-model="alert.cautionMultiplier" id="cautionMultiplier" name="cautionMultiplier" placeholder="Ex. 2" integer required />
            <span>{{alertForm}}</span>
            <span class="alert alert-danger help-block" ng-show="alertForm.cautionMultiplier.$error.number && alertForm.amount.$dirty">
                                    The value is not a valid integer
                                </span>
            <span class="alert alert-danger help-block" ng-show="alertForm.cautionMultiplier.$error.min ">
                                    The value must be at least 1 and an integer
                                </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="addAlert(form)" ng-disabled="alertForm.$invalid">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I enter **any non integer (ie 'a')** into the `cautionMultiplier` box, the validation message `The value is not a valid integer` does not trigger.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

My problem was that: `alertForm.amount.$dirty` should have been `alertForm.cautionMultiplier.$dirty`

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying this error message only if there is an error for the key "required":

```
ng-show="alertForm.cautionMultiplier.$error.required && alertForm.amount.$dirty"
```

Replace `required` by `number`.

Comment: I made that change and still nothing... I reflected the change in an edit above.

Comment: Ah, my problem was that: `alertForm.amount.$dirty` should have been `alertForm.cautionMultiplier.$dirty`